# Xcode wrong WatchExtension in target schemes

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have a Xcode project with two targets for slightly different iOS apps. Both these apps also have a `widget` and an `Apple Watch app` so in total there are 8 targets in my project. I'll just call them `Target1` and `Target2` for now.

I was trying to run the `Target2Watch` app because I noticed some strange things. I could get it running at all and got a strange error message from `Target1WatchExtension`. I was confused because that's not the correct extension for the watch app so I searched a bit further.

I noticed that the schemes for `Target1` are all correct but for `Target2` and `Target2Watch` there were some strange configurations. Here are screenshots of the schemes:

[image]
[image]

A colleague made the targets and I know that he duplicated `Target1` to create `Target2`. My guess is something went wrong there.

What I cannot figure out is how to change the `WatchExtension` for `Target2` because when I select it the minus button is disabled. `Target2Watch` has the same problem with the wrong `WatchExtension` so I need to change that as well.

How can I edit `WatchExtensions` for a scheme or is the scheme correct but are the target settings the problem?

PS. I'm using Xcode 7.3 and watchOS 2.0

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem: I've solved my problem thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33149506/2240769).

1. Open `project.pbxproj` in a text editor (right click on `YourProject.xcodeproj` and choose `Show Package Contents` to find it)
2. Find the line `/* Begin PBXNativeTarget section */`
3. Go to the target with the wrong extension and change the line

   - `productType = "com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2";`
   - to
   - `productType = "com.apple.product-type.application";`
4. Open your project and select your target with the wrong extension
5. Select `Build Phases`
6. Remove wrong extensions in `Target Dependencies` and `Embed App Extension` and add correct extensions
7. Go back to your `project.pbxproj` file in the text editor and change the `productType` of the target back to `"com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2";`
8. Et voila everything should be fine now